# Customize QListWidgetItem

Tags: qt, customization, qlistwidget

I am creating my first app in QT and wanted to design a list. The listitem has two texts and one icon.

The problem is, i cant find any example or helping material, Only helping link i found is : [Customize QListWidgetItem](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/27777-Customize-QListWidgetItem-how-to) but i dont understand it. Although i have the same problem which this links points to...

What i understand is, i have two options:

1- Customize QListWidgetItem to use with QListWidget

2- Make some delegate to use with QListView

I was hoping to get started with option 1. Now in the link, some reply talks about **"myItem"** which is taking 2 texts as input. I want to know the implementation of **"myItem"**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the link you posted, `MyItem` is just a normal `QWidget`. This means that you can create a widget in Qt Designer and then set that new widget you created as the widget that the `QListWidgetItem` should use for display. In the above example, `MyItem` takes two strings because there is a vertical layout with two labels in it (that's my assumption at least).

You should also note, and is discussed in the above link, that taking the approach of setting an item widget to use for every item in the list is an expensive thing to do in terms of performance and memory consumption. Because a `QListWidget` is a `QListView`, you can set an item delegate on it just like any other view and come out with a lighter weight solution (one instantiation of class vs. one instantiation for every item in your list)

Comment: Thanx for the answer, i do require some clearifications though; as i m very new in QT.    
1- I dont have any Qt Designer, now how to create a widget? and would it also make a class for that widget so that i can pass two QLabels in it just like in the link?    2- QListView is better than QListWidget? (I suppose yes) then i have to move to Delegate thing; of which unfortunately i dont have any clue...    Now Detailed answers are not required, i dont want to take much of your time but concepts and links are very welcomed.  +1 for answering... :) i'll surely accept it later.

Comment: You can create a widget in code as well as in designer. Designer is just a visual tool that makes it much easier to do so. If you downloaded the Qt SDK, then you should have Qt Designer. I'm surprised you don't have it. If you use QListView, your application will have a lighter footprint as far as memory goes. The model-view programming guide at http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/model-view-programming.html should be a huge help. The Qt docs are an excellent tool for increasing your Qt knowledge. They're at http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7 (for Qt 4.7, which is the latest version)

Comment: Well yes, i dont have a designer, i tried to un-install and re-install the qtsdk but noop; no designer. anyways i have to make a widget like "myitem" so it would be easy if i can do it through design but programmatically its quite difficult. So could you help me in creating the widget through Qt Creator? my gmail id: me.farhanahmad@gmail.com if you can get some time for chat :) otherwise no problem.

Comment: Creating a widget programmactically and then using setItemWidget(QListWidgetItem,MyWidget) solves the problem but it would be lot easier if i had a designer... :( anyways thanx matt..